# Error - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: 20.04, mongodb, segmentation-fault

I just installed Mongodb compass in my Ubuntu OS(Ubuntu 20.04) I opened the termianal and typed `mongodb-compass` I got the error - Segmentation fault (core dumped).

I also tried to open by clicking icon but nothing worked.

Comment: Please add the output of `which mongodb-compass` , `dpkg -S $(which mongodb-compass)` and `apt-cache policy $(which mongodb-compass)` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I am using mongodb-compass 1.15.1-1. And in the next command, I am getting error - dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *$*

Comment: Then how did you installed mongodb-compass?

Comment: by running these commands  ```sudo apt-get update``` , ```wget https://downloads.mongodb.com/compass/mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb``` and ```sudo dpkg -i mongodb-compass_1.15.1_amd64.deb```

Comment: I have the same behaviour on fresh 20.04 LTS VM. So it is not a harddrive problem.

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.

Comment: @N0rbert how to resolve it?

Comment: Really I do not know, maybe try older version...